# Como podria hacer click en este elemento usando selenium con python?

Tags: python, selenium

estoy usando selenium con python. Quiero poder hacer click en esta opcion

```
<option value="" selected="selected">
                        TODOS LOS VENDEDORES
                    </option>
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vale... me ha funcionado asi:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 6)\
        .until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
        "//select/option[@value='']")))\
        .click()
```

Comment: Por favor se más descriptivo con tu respuesta y pregunta. La idea del sitio es que un usuario que tenga un problema similar al tuyo tenga facilidad para entender qué está pasando y cómo solucionarlo. Al poner solo el código, sin descripciones o comentarios se disminuye la legibilidad del código; que si bien es claro para tí, no lo es para otro usuario que no conoce el contexto de tu solución.

Comment: Ups  perdon!!!!!   me encontraba intentando hacer click en un option value que no tenia ningun valor entre comillas... es decir comilla vacia. Ahora mismo no se me ocurre que mas indicar para facilitar su comprension.  Si alguien necesita alguna aclaracion mas, cuenten conmigo para aclararles  dentro de mis posibilidades.  Gracias FranAcuna!!